# Median based on number of entries instead of values

Tags: statistics, definition, median

I’m writing a computer program that provides some useful statistical information about files. Calculating the mean is trivial, and the mode at least has a simple definition, but the median is proving tricky. I remember its general definition from school, but there is some ambiguity.

> Median: the “middle number”.

But what does that mean? Is it the middle *entry* or the middle *value*?

The [Wikipedia page for *mean*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Easy_explanation_of_the_sample_median) uses the sample data set `1, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8` and gives the median as 4 because the mean of the two middle *entries* (2 and 6) is 4.

But what about 6? The number 6 has the same number of *values* above (7,8) as it does below (1,2).

This is a pretty useful statistic as well. Is there a name for this?

Comment: You have to think it as an equilibrium point.

Comment: The centre of gravity is the mean.

Comment: By most reasonable interpretations, if you count 2 as just one "value", you'd still want to give it twice as much weight in almost anything you do, as you would if it had been there only once.

Comment: @Synetech : True: I've never thought the mode was good for much.

Comment: @Synetech : I had in mind the mode of a quantitative variable rather than a categorical one.  (But I don't know how much the mode is worth in TV ratings either, unless it's for winning awards.)

Comment: @Synetech : If one discarded multiplicities and kept only the values, then there wouldn't even be such a thing as the mode, since the mode is the one with the largest multiplicity.

Comment: @Synetech : I wrote " if you count 2 as just one "value", you'd still want to give it twice as much weight in almost anything you do, as you would if it had been there only once." and then you responded that that would make the mode practically useless.  But in fact, the mode becomes meaningless if you don't weight data points by their multiplicities.

Answer (score 1):

The notion you are looking for is [sample median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#The_sample_median) (as opposed to population median).

**Sort** the sample values, respecting multiplicity. So if we got $7.8$ three times, we write it down $3$ times. One can use non-decreasing order or non-increasing order, it doesn't matter.

If the number of sample values is odd, say $2k+1$, then the sample median is the "middle" value, that is, the $(k+1)$-th value counting from the bottom (or top) of the sorted list.

If the number of sample values is odd, say $2k$, then the sample median is the ordinary average of the two "middle" values. the $k$-th and the $(k+1)$-th.

Comment: If you look a few lines down from the anchor you linked to on that page, you’ll see that it is the one that gives 4 as the median. I’m looking for a term for the calculation that would return 6. I tried looking for *population median* instead, but it was only used four times in the page and none of them defined it as what I’m wondering about (or at all for that matter).

Comment: Population median is defined for a probability distribution. In the case of "ambiguity" of the type we meet with samples, **all** "middle" values are declared to be medians. So in our case it would be all numbers between $0$ and $6$ inclusive. The top of this range of medians, and the bottom, have no special names. In the finite case, any point $p$ that minimizes the sum of the absolute values $\sum |x_i-p|$ is a median.

Comment: Discarding entries that happen to repeat would not make statistical sense. One could call the result $6$ the median of the **set** of values.

Comment: `Discarding entries that happen to repeat would not make statistical sense.`   How so? Most statistics ignore some attribute or another. The mode ignores *all* of the other values, and yet is frequently used.     `One could call the result 6 the median of the set of values.`   “Could” because there is no existing, formal name?

Comment: There is no existing name that I know of used in Statistics. The median of the set of values is technically the correct name

Comment: Okay, that sounds reasonable. I’m just surprised it hasn’t come up more. I also can’t find much about the formula `(lo+hi)/2`. The closest to that is range, but not quite. There’s plenty of attributes for a set of data and you never know which might be the most useful for a particular application.

Comment: The mean of low and high does not look like a good measure of central tendency, because of its sensitivity to outliers. But there are quite a number of related important statistics, such as interquartile mean and trimean.

Comment: `The mean of low and high does not look like a good measure of central tendency, because of its sensitivity to outliers.`   True, but the same could be said of the range in general (that it’s not a very useful/representative statistic). Besides, it depends on the data set (or rather, what the numbers represent and are used for). In any case, I just want to dump lots of different attributes to look at and figure out which one is most useful for this specific task; most of these are just basic statistics, not exactly $R^2$.